# System Messages ext issue

Tags: error, newrelic, custom-system-messages

I am using new relic to watch my EE install and am seeing a ton of slowness around this call.

I am also using http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages  - and am not sure if the issue is coming from that plugin or the EE system messages.

Has anyone seen this before?

System_­messages_­ext­:­:extend_­output_­class

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Jordan, can you post this over at boldminded.com/support? Include version of EE, and maybe FTP access so I can debug this. There are several other calls in there with 93% and 6,320 ms, so the CSM call isn't much different.

Comment: Are you sure it's tied to custom system messages vs being something from EE itself?